# Subjuntivo en la frase comparativa

Tags: subjuntivo

> Resultó más lento de lo que **hubiera imaginado**.

¿Me podríais aclarar una duda por favor? ¿Se puede decir que aquí se trata de la alternancia modo subjuntivo <> condicional (*Resultó más lento de lo que habría imaginado*.) o se emplea el subjuntivo pluscuamperfecto simplemente porque se trata de una comparación irreal en el pasado?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es en efecto un caso de alternancia entre el pluscuamperfecto del  subjuntivo y el condicional compuesto. El sentido es pasado hipotético. Podemos imaginar una condicional implícita:

- Resultó más lento de lo que hubiera/habría imaginado si le hubieran preguntado cuánto tardaría.

En cambio, el pluscuamperfecto indicativo sugeriría que en efecto lo imaginó, y que lo que había imaginado no se cumplió.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias!